# Is it secure to store password in C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it secure to have a password as a plain string in the c# code? I will only have one user that will use the login feature.
Thank you.

Comment: Probably not. You should Hash and Encrypt it, event when inside code.

Comment: No. C# code is easily decompiled to it's (near-enough) exact source.

Comment: While the answer really is "no", the issue is mitigated with code running on the server (eg ASP.NET) *if* nobody can access the assembly directly. However, code on the client - very bad place to store a secret password. There are also better ways to store passwords than *in* the code; the web.config file, for instance, supports encryption of such.

Comment: Im looking for the simplest way to store a password, do you have any suggestions? This site wont be exposed to any "real" threats.

Comment: Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908438/how-can-i-secure-passwords-stored-inside-my-web-config-file

Comment: you can store it encrypted in a txt file, you can use this: https://encrypto.codeplex.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it isn't secure, as the others have already said, it's not a complicated matter to decompile a dll etc and retrieve the source code...

Perhaps you could look into putting it an an app key in the web.config file and encrypt that using IIS... [Have a read of this Microsoft walkthrough for encrypting the web.config connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dtkwfdky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Link is broken so please use this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

**No**, it's not safe. Many decompilers like [reflectors](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) can easily retrieve the password, main reason for it is code can be easily decompiled.