# ASP.NET How to store a username and password in a secure way in website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I build a website and i need to use web service.
One of the function in the web service I need to send username and password and for that i want to store them somewhere in the website(in the server side).

I looked that i can store in the web.config in appSettings like : `<add key="UsernameForWS" value="username"/>`and use in the class with `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UsernameForWS"]`

**My question is what i found is secure or there is a better way to do this?**

Comment: Writing password out in plain text is the most unsecure way to store them. _In any place!_

Comment: But you really should explain better what are your trying to do. In particular the part whre you say _I need to send username and password_

Comment: i would recommend using a hashing technique and storing them in the database.

Comment: If your website is still IIS hosted you can encrypt config sections. https://stackoverflow.com/q/20908438/314291

Comment: Encrypt Decrypt Web.Config section using aspnet_regiis.exe https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Encrypt-decrypt-WebConfig-section-using-aspnetregiisexe.aspx